# How to execute 'iftop' without sudo

Tags: linux, unix, sudoers

I have a script that runs `iftop` in text mode, cuts down the output to what I'm concerned in, and saves it to a text file along with the output of the `date` command (I am monitoring network usage on various interfaces over time). Only problem I'm having is I'm trying to run my script every 15 minutes via the crontab, and in order to run the `iftop` command I need sudo permissions. Does anyone know some way to change the permissions of `iftop` to make it so I don't need sudo permissions?

Alternatively if I can give the script the ability to run the command with sudo that would be fine by me as well. I tried adding the script to the sudoers file via `sudo visudo` and adding the line:

`user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/user/network_usage.sh`

but that didn't work...perhaps a result of executing from the crontab?

Thanks,

-Eric

Comment: Can you please elaborate on in what way the sudo version didn't work? That **should** work, as far as I'm concerned...

Comment: Is this with `sudo /home/user/network_usage.sh` in your crontab?

Comment: My script is supposed to output `interface_sent: rate` and `interface_received: rate` but currently the rates come up blank (I'm guessing that part of the script is unable to run because of the sudo problem). Also if I try and execute the script manually it still asks for sudo password.

Comment: No there is no sudo in the crontab, only in the script. Would adding sudo to the crontab make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use root's crontab to run the script.
If instead of `crontab -e` you use `sudo crontab -e` you will edit root's crontab. Tasks specified in that file will run under root's account and privileges.

Alternatively, you can set the setuid access flag for your script file. To do so first change the owner of the file to root, then enable setuid like this:

```
sudo chown root /home/user/network_usage.sh
sudo chmod +s-w /home/user/network_usage.sh
```

The setuid bit makes an executable file run with the effective UID of its owner.

Regardless of what approach you take, be **very careful**.

- Make your script owned by root and don't let any other user write to it, otherwise it could ease a privilege escalation.
- Be aware of the side effects of your setuid programs. If the script has setuid and may create or modify files, it might be used by someone else to modify or create files they aren't supposed to. Always check the manual before giving setuid to any program you haven't written.

Comment: I tried the sudo crontab and it worked, thanks for both methods though I appreciate the in-depth answer.

Answer (score 7):

A more granular approach would be to use:

```
# setcap cap_net_raw=eip $(which iftop)
```

This lets iftop capture packets but does not give the process full root privileges. In case of a security problem or bug with "iftop" its side effects would be much more limited.

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189750/how-can-i-run-script-without-root-to-sniff-network-libpcap

Comment: This is the proper way to do it in any remotely-recent Linux distro. Using `setcap` enables to you allow the minimum set of privileges required by `iftop`, as opposed to using `chmod +s` which is equivalent to throwing the kitchen sink at the problem. This is most certainly the best practice from a security POV.

Answer (score 2):

If you have root access on the machine the quick and dirty way:

```
chmod +s $(which iftop)
```

This will make it run w/ root privileges no matter who invokes it.
But I still think your sudo like **should** work.

Comment: Thank you for that. Saved me a lot of time.